# Errors, warnings and messages playconsole. how can i fix?

Tags: android-security

Zip Path Traversal
Your app contains an unsafe unzipping pattern that may lead to a Path Traversal vulnerability. Please see this Google Help Center article to learn how to fix the issue.

com.startapp.networkTest.utils.j.a
com.startapp.sdk.adsbase.j.n.a

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, but I solved it with the latest version of SDK implementation 'com.startapp:inapp-sdk:4.9.2'

From Javadoc https://javadoc.io/doc/com.startapp/inapp-sdk/latest/index.html

greetings!